# Uncaught TypeError: _particles2.default.load is not a function - React, create-react-app, particlesJS

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, particles.js

Am having trouble importing the [particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) library.

Am using create-react-app, and am following the instructions on the particles js github page also.

After initiating 'create-react-app', I install particles.js

```
npm install particles.js --save
```

then in the App.js file the relevant parts I have are:

```
import particlesJS from 'particles.js'

componentDidMount(){
    //particles.js github page says to load package like so:
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
      console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });
},

render() {
    return (
       <div>
            //div to include particles canvas, as specified in particles.js github page         
            <div id="particles-js"></div>
       </div>
);
```

}

However the console gives the error
    Uncaught TypeError: _particles2.default.load is not a function

And if I put to console.log(particlesJS) it gives an empty object, so I am pretty sure the problem is with how I am loading the package. Basically, the package is not even being loaded, that is why there is no .load() function available on the particlesJS object.

Any ideas how to fix this?

By the way, have got the package working through the '[react-particles-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js)' package, however still curious to see how to get it to work by using the package.js package directly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like the library was written without regard for JavaScript bundlers, so it's not really working with the `import` statement like you would expect. Instead it sets a global variable on the `window` object.

So to use it you could do something like:

```
import 'particles.js/particles';
const particlesJS = window.particlesJS;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked. Thank you! For reference the particles json config file should be stored in the 'public folder'

Comment: `const particlesJS = (<any>window).particlesJS` if you which to use it within an angular component

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried to use it with NExt.js 13 , and with your advice it's working well 

Comment: Thank you a lot! I tried to use it with NExt.js 13 , and with your advice it's working well 