# Include particles.js into rails / webpack project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, particles.js

I have a project based on Rails 6.0.0.rc2 including webpack. I am trying to include simply the library particles.js

I am following the GitHub readme:
  - Install the library with yarn
  - Add a container with a specific id
  - Try to initialize the function using particlesJS.load

Obviously, it is not working: particleJS is not defined

> particle_js__webpack_imported_module_0___default.a.load is not a
>   function

After reading a lot of questions on this topic but nothing is really clear. here are some leads but I did not succeed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42457020/11027833
- https://github.com/vigetlabs/blendid/issues/287
- https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/114

I understood that particleJS is linked to the window object. And indeed, when I try in the console particleJS, it works.

So could you tell me simply how to use particleJS with webpack? Or how to use a window function into webpack?

Thank you in advance for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Rails+webpacker mayhem. In theory you would do something like:

```
let particlejs = require("particlejs");
```

That goes in your pack file. Then you have particlejs available in your window object.

You can also do:

```
// config/webpack/custom.js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
      particle_js: 'particlejs'
    }
  }
}
```

Also try this:

```
import 'particles.js/particles';
const particlesJS = window.particlesJS;
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I can't figure out how it works.
Doing this `let particlejs = require("particlejs"); ` does not work because the library does not export a module.
For the second option, I don't understand how it works. If I add the code in a new file custom.js, what do I do after? How do I call `particlesJS.load` which is the function that initialize the particles?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue, here is what I did to get it working.

If you're using yarn to install/add packages then run the following command from the root of your application to add the particles.js to the node_modules folder:

```
yarn add particles.js
```

Now open up ***app/javascript/packs/application.js*** and add the following:

```
require("particles.js")
```

Now restart your rails server and it should work.